# Xsl transforms correctly choosing children but not on ancestor in indesign?

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I am experiencing a strange problem with xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
 <xsl:copy> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|*[not(self::table)]"/> 
 </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@value"> 
 <xsl:attribute name="value"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xd;','&#xa;')"/> 
 </xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:text>[b]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>[/b]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:text>[i]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>[/i]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@href"/>
```

My Xml looks like this:

```
<medium>
     <sheets>
          <sheet>
               <site>
                    All Elements
               </site>
          </sheet>
     </sheets>
</medium>
```

A `<text-area>` tag will look like this:

```
<text-area>
     <text>
          this is the <b>normal</b> indesign content
     </text>
</text-area>.
```

After xsl:

```
<text-area>
     <text value="this is the [b]normal[/b] indesign content"/>
</text-area>
```

Now the Problem:

When I export it in indesign and choose sheets, sheet, site or any other element where `<text-area>` is a child, it exports it as:

```
<text-area>
     <text value="this is the [b]normal[/b] indesign content"/>
</text-area>
```

ONLY when I choose medium it will look like this:

```
<text-area>
     <text value="this is the normal indesign content">
          this is the <b>normal</b> indesign content
     </text>
</text-area>
```

Why is this happening? I have NO idea... Why is it working on every other element other than "medium"?

Complete xml example:

```
<medium xmlns="example" xmlns:xsi="example" xsi:schemaLocation="example" name="Karte" description="asd" summary="asd" id="Karte_3/11/2015/16">
  <thumbnail src="http://karte/thumb.png"/>
  <sales-plan>
    <download price="3"/>
  </sales-plan>
  <sheets>
    <sheet>
      <site width="216.0" height="111.0" trim="3">
        <text-area x="116.00000007" y="32.10000002" width="88.00" height="51.60" line-height="8.4666666720" readonly="true" text-align="left" orientation="0">
          <text>
            <b>Ein herzlich frohes Weihnachtsfest, viel Freude, Glück und Gesundheit für das Neue Jahr.</b>
          </text>
          <font size="7.0555555600"/>
          <foreground-color c="0" m="0" y="0" k="0"/>
        </text-area>
        <graphic-area x="-0.00000000" y="98.30000006" width="216.00" height="12.70" orientation="0">
          <foreground-color-ref idref="user-color"/>
          <svg>
            <g class="user-color" style="fill:[user-color];">
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:[user-color];"/>
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill=" #000" style="fill-opacity:0"/>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </graphic-area>
        <text-area x="10.20000000" y="102.00416673" width="202.800000" height="5.995833" line-height="4.2333333360" readonly="true" text-align="left" orientation="0">
          <text value="[user-firmname] · [user-firstname] [user-lastname] · [user-street] [user-housenr] · [user-zipcode] [user-city]">Firmenname · Ansprechpartner · Straße H.Nr. · PLZ · Ort</text>
          <font size="3.5277777800" weight="normal"/>
          <foreground-color c="0" m="0" y="0" k="0"/>
        </text-area>
      </site>
    </sheet>
  </sheets>
</medium>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are some people here that know XSLT, but very few know both Indesign _and_ XSLT I assume. So, perhaps you could explain what **choosing** an element while exporting in Indesign exactly means?

Comment: Could you post a minimal but **complete** example of an XML that we could copy, apply your XSLT to it and reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MathiasMüller in the structure in Indesign you have the option to "export from selected element". When I choose "Medium" it will export the Medium as root element and all children of this. When I choose "Sheets" it wont include "medium", as "sheets" is a child of "medium". Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: @michael.hor257k added a complete xml example

Comment: I suspect @MathiasMüller gave you the correct answer. However, the result that you show above is **not** the actual result received when running the code, so there could be another thing at play, too. But more likely, you haven't reproduced the actual result corerctly.

Comment: I didn't think you want the result, but rather what xml is to be exported?

Comment: "*I didn't think you want the result, but rather what xml is to be exported?*" True, but if I cannot reproduce the result, then I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Actually I meant the text being output twice, once as an attribute and once on its own. Anyway, I don't think it matters now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `medium` element declares a *default* namespace that you need to take into account. If you choose to export from the `medium` element, this default namespace applies to the `medium` element and all its descendants - including the `text` and `b` element.

Now, a template that matches

```
<xsl:template match="b">
```

only matches elements that are in *no* namespace. To find a `b` element that is in a default namespace, you need to *redeclare* this namespace in the stylesheet and prefix the element name in the template match.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:ex="example">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
 <xsl:copy> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|*[not(self::table)]"/> 
 </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@value"> 
 <xsl:attribute name="value"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xd;','&#xa;')"/> 
 </xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="ex:text">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="ex:b">
    <xsl:text>[b]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>[/b]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="ex:i">
    <xsl:text>[i]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>[/i]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@href"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

Only the part that matters:

```
<text value="&#xA;            [b]Ein herzlich frohes Weihnachtsfest, viel Freude, Glück und Gesundheit für das Neue Jahr.[/b]&#xA;          "/>
```

---

By the way, if you'd like the stylesheet to work regardless of namespaces present in the input XML, use the following stylesheet. I also simplified the templates matching `b` and `i` elements, because both templates did essentially the same.

Are you sure you need to apply templates to `*[not(self::table)]`? It would be cleaner to apply templates to everything in the identity template and write another template

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'table']"/>
```

to prevent `table` elements from being output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|*[not(self::table)]"/> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="@value"> 
     <xsl:attribute name="value"> 
         <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xd;','&#xa;')"/> 
     </xsl:attribute> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'text']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'b' or local-name() = 'i']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',local-name(),']')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[/',local-name(),']')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@href"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: @FrederikWitte I won't believe that Indesign spells _prefix_ wrong. Anyway, this is most likely because the namespace URI in your input XML sample is _not really_ "example", but something else.

Comment: I noticed this, sorry :P I wrote before I saw your second example, which seems to be much more logical(but also harder to understand)

Comment: Also, you are right with the table. I think it was the same problem as I had before. I tried to match just "table". Everything works now! Thank you so much!